# Clear:Both makes green square go out the div

Tags: html, css, sass

This 1st picture is what i am trying to achieve

[image: what i am trying to imitate]

However, all i am able to do is this

[image: error]

As you can see, the last green square is outside of the last lightblue div, and the "Some Text" is also at the bottom outside it's div.

I've been using clear:both and clear:left but this is what happens.

Here is my HTML and **SCSS code**

```css
@import 'reset';

div {
 width: 440px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  // overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}


.red, .green, .blue, .yellow {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;

}

.green {
  background: green;
}

#two {
 .red, .green, .blue {
  float: right;
 }
}

#three {
 .red {
  float: right;
 }
}

#four {
 height: 66px;

 p {
  // border: 1px solid black;
  clear: left;
 }

 .blue {
  float: right;
 }
}

#five {
 height: 100px;

 .blue {
  float: right;
 }

 .green {
  clear: left; /*clear:left*/
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Floats</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <p>Float</p>
  <div>
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="five">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
 </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit of a mess to answer here, because the interpreter here on SO can understand *css* but not *scss*. I've erased a lot of the scss specific styles and translated those I need into plain css. You should be able to convert back to scss easily enough.

To make your container divs expand to hold your floated child divs, I used `overflow: hidden`. I also removed the height properties (from the containers) so height is set by the content. And `clear: both` or `clear: left` should work for the paragraph in the code below.

```css
@import 'reset';

div {
 width: 440px;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.red, .green, .blue, .yellow {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;

}

.green {
  background: green;
}

#four p {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Floats</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <p>Float</p>
  <div>
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="five">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="blue"></div>
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
 </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to how [CSS Selectors work](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) because you *don't* put selectors in that way when you want to specify a selector for an element that is inside another element, you just use `outer_element inner_element`, for example `#two .red`.

Apart from that you got the rest almost right, the other problem was that you were applying rules to all `div`' elements that should only apply to the containers, so the margin of the containers was applied also to the squares.

```css
@import 'reset';
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
  width: 440px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.red, .green, .blue, .yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

#two .red, #two .green, #two .blue {
  float: right;
}

#three .red {
  float: right;
}

#four {
  height: 70px;
}

#four p {
  clear: left;
}

#four .blue {
  float: right;
}

#five {
  height: 100px;
}

#five .blue {
  float: right;
}

#five .green {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Floats</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <p>Float</p>
    <div id="one">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="three">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="four">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="five">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```